# Is this a bug in OpenCV 3.0 or I am doing something wrong?

Tags: c++, opencv

I installed OpenCv 3.0 alpha and tried the sample code from this tutorial:

http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/tutorials/photo/hdr_imaging/hdr_imaging.html

the result for tone mapped is not good and it generate a lot of false colours.

[image]

also the fusion doesn't work and generate an error:

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (y == 0 || (data && dims >= 1 && (unsigned)y < (u nsigned)size.p[0])) in cv::Mat::ptr, file C:\builds\master_PackSlave-win64-vc11- static\opencv\modules\core\include\opencv2/core/mat.inl.hpp, line 750
```

it is happening on this line in code (on pyrUp call) in my case where I have 7 images, it crashes when lvl is 4.:

```
for(int lvl = 0; lvl < maxlevel; lvl++) {
    Mat up;
    pyrUp(img_pyr[lvl + 1], up, img_pyr[lvl].size());
    img_pyr[lvl] -= up;
 }
```

I am testing this code on visual studio 2012 on windows 7. My project is a x64 bit project.

Comment: Try the same code with the stable one (2.4.9).

Comment: @C.R. 2.4.9 Doesn't have HDR capability!

Comment: It seems you are overflowing `img_pyr` and reading garbage or reading empty Mat. What is its size? Is `+1` intentional in `img_pyr[lvl + 1]` ?   I can't conclude much with this code.

Comment: @PervezAlam This is not my code. I just step into code inside OpenCv code and found the place that it generate error. This is the reason that I asked if it is a bug in opencv or a bug in my code. My code is exactly as explained in tutorial.

Comment: Hi @mans, this assertion means either the Mat or its data or pointer is empty or uninitialized *or* the dimension is 0 or uninitialized. When the function `pyrUp` is called and it starts read that Mat, it is asserting, so most probably img_pyr is needed to be checked for size/boundary and initialization. Good Luck :)